# Syntax errors in React Native components AccessibilityInfo and ActivityIndicator when trying to compile a release build

Tags: javascript, react-native

Using RN 0.61.5 (also happened on 0.61.4)

It happens whether I execute `react-native run-android --variant=release` or `gradlew assembleRelease` directly.

I tried reinstalling the said modules, to no avail.

I also deleted the node_modules folder and ran `npm cache clear --force` and it did nothing.

The babel parser and the cli-platform-android modules are also at the latest version

```
error SyntaxError: C:\dev\my-app\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\AccessibilityInfo\AccessibilityInfo.android.js: Unexpected token, expected ";" (21:5)

  19 | const TOUCH_EXPLORATION_EVENT = 'touchExplorationDidChange';
  20 |
> 21 | type ChangeEventName = $Keys<{
     |      ^
  22 |   change: string,
  23 |   reduceMotionChanged: string,
  24 |   screenReaderChanged: string,. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
```

Comment: Not sure if related, but I see latest docs say to use `npx react-native` instead of globally installed react-native: "If you previously installed a global react-native-cli package, please remove it as it may cause unexpected issues." - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Comment: I have the exact same result using npx react-native, unfortunately...